# Is it possible to convert a string to an int[] using only lambda expressions?

Tags: java, arrays, lambda

I was thinking of converting this `String`: `1 2 3 4 5 6` to an `int[]` using only lambda expressions. I was thinking of something along the lines of

`int[] x = Arrays.asList(scan.nextLine().split(" ")).stream.forEach(it -> Integer.parseInt(it));` but this is syntactically invalid.

Comment: `stream` is a method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just a couple of small improvement on @Jason's answer to remove the conversion to list and return an `int[]` rather than `Integer[]`:

```
int[] result = Pattern.compile(" ").splitAsStream("1 2 3 4 5")
    .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
    .toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind the result being an `Integer[]`:

```
String s = "1 2 3 4 5";
int[] x = Arrays.stream(s.split(" "))
        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
        .toArray();
```

Comment: Why not just use `Arrays.stream(s.split(" "))`?

Comment: Result is not an `int[]`, as requested, but `Integer[]`. Use `mapToInt` instead.